# How to escape this callback hell

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm currently trying to fetch data from public API about a country and its neighboring countries to render on my html. 
renderCountry( ) is a function to implement on my html with the data I will receive.
I also excluded some unnecessary codes, which I believe is not major in this particular case.

This is how I fetch data:

```
const getCountryAndNeighbour = function(country) {
    fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${country}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            renderCountry(data[0]);
            const neighbour = data[0].borders;    
            neighbour.forEach(country => {
                fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/alpha/${country}`)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => renderCountry(data, `neighbour`))
            });
        })
}
```

Here, you will see callback hell architecture. Any idea for escape from that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use `async/await`.

Comment: Whatever you do, `forEach` doesn't work with promises. Fix that first.

Comment: I wouldn't call this callback hell. You already use promise chaining just fine, and have only two levels of `.then` callbacks - the nesting is necessary and unavoidable because of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite it using [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

eg.

```
const getCountryAndNeighbour = async country => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${country}`);
  const data = await response.json();

  renderCountry(data[0]);

  const neighbour = data[0].borders;
  neighbour.forEach(async country => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/alpha/${country}`)
    const data = await response.json();

    renderCountry(data, `neighbour`);
  });
};
```

Please note that forEach will run all promises in the same time.

If you want to run one by one you should use eg. for loop or some util like [Bluebird.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) which allows you to specify a concurrency

Good luck!

Comment: You [cannot use `forEach` for asynchronous code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi I did write "Please note that forEach will run all promises in the same time."

Comment: Yes, and that's why it should be avoided. Even if you don't need to wait for anything since there is currently no code after the `forEach()`, it's a footgun waiting to be fired.

Comment: I know. I gave a starting point and wrote that he can use a for loop or Bluebird.map for making it better. I didn't want to give a whole fish but encourage him for using a fishing rod

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). You would add `async` before the function keyword and add await as needed. See below to see this in action:

```js
const getCountryAndNeighbour = async function (country) {
    const res = await fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${country}`)
    const data = await res.json();

    renderCountry(data[0]);
    const neighbour = data[0].borders;
    await Promise.all(
        neighbour.map(async country => {
            let response = await fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/alpha/${country}`)
            response = await response.json();
            return renderCountry(response, 'neighbour');
        });
    );
}
```

Comment: You [cannot use `forEach` for asynchronous code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/1048572).

Comment: I changed it to the `map()` function.

Comment: That alone won't suffice

Comment: Would you do this then?

Comment: I'd add the `await Promise.all(…)` around it

Comment: So like this? 

```Promise.all(neighbour).then(async(country) => {
    let response = await fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/alpha/${country}`)
    response = await response.json();
    return renderCountry(response, 'neighbour');
});```

Comment: No, `await Promise.all(neighbour.map(async country => {…}));`. See also the link in my first comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241230/discussion-between-k-k-desgins-and-bergi).

Comment: Ok, done! It's added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**This will do using Async/await**

```
async function getCountryData(country) {
    const response = await fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${country}`);
    return await response.json();
}

async function getNeighbourData(country) {
    const response = await fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/alpha/${country}`);
    return await response.json();
}

async function getCountryAndNeighbour(country) {
    const data = await getCountryData(country);
    const neighbourCountries = data[1].borders;

    for (const neighbour of neighbourCountries) {
        const response = await getNeighbourData(neighbour);
        console.log(response);
    }
}
```

Add the necessary validations when checking [0]/[1] in your function.